# Is it possible to specify port-offset in JBoss domain master configuration?

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x, jboss-eap-6

I have jboss-eap-6.1 that I want to run domain. There are a few other services running on the machine that use same ports this server needs. I can't seem to find the way to specify the port-offset to shift the ports used by this installation.
I know it's possible to offset in standalone mode, but I need to set the server up in domain mode.

I appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify offset for each server which will be ran on your local machine - and this belongs to `host.xml`.

```
<servers>
    <server name="server" group="main-server-group" auto-start="true">
        <socket-binding-group port-offset="150"/>
    </server>
</servers>
```

See also JBoss [domain tutorial](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Domain+Setup) for reference.

Comment: I get this:
JBAS010932: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: JBAS014676: Failed to parse configuration
...
 Message: JBAS014788: Unexpected attribute 'ref' encountered

Comment: Sorry, you don't need `ref` attribute - I've edited my answer

Comment: Still I"m getting the same error 'Address already in use'. I really need to offset all the ports.

Answer (score 1):

Question is now quiet old but still unanswered, it may help someone else.

Petr was almost there. You indeed need to edit your host.xml, but as following:

```
<servers> 
    <server name="server" group="main-server-group" auto-start="true"> 
         <socket-bindings port-offset="150"/> 
    </server>
</server>
```